# AWS Lambda http GET method in Java

Tags: java, http, aws-lambda, get, http-get

I am writing a AWS Lambda function in java but struggling to make a http `get` request probably because I am not passing the correct `User-Agent` parameter.

The error status return is 403

Can someone please tell me what should i specify in `User-Agent` specifically in AWS lambda function?

Or any alternative way to use the get request in java ?

When I run the same code in my desktop environment with `User-Agent` as "Mozilla/5.0" the code works fine and return 200.

Below is my Java code:

```java
public Object handleRequest(Object request, Context context){

        
    try {

        String vAdress = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states"
        URL vURL = new URL(vAdress);

        HttpURLConnection vConnection = (HttpURLConnection) vURL.openConnection();
        vConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //vConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java client");
        //vConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "agent");     
        System.out.println(vConnection.getResponseCode());


    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return ioe.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that Lambdas probably don't pass user agent information in requests since this information is usually a way to identify the browser that made the request. A Lambda does not run in a browser environment. It seems that the problem is not necessarily the Lambda but maybe the API you're sending requests to. Can you log the full response from the API and maybe also the full request? It seems that the API is expecting something that is not present in your request when sent via a Lambda.

Comment: I don't think it a AWS lambda problem. What happens when you just set mozilla user agent on lambda like `vConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 5 Build/_BuildID_)");`.

Because without proper user agent API is giving 403, and when the User agent is set it gives 200 status code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use API Gateway to proxy requests to your lambda function and then set up a [mapping template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) to pass through the user-agent to your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at configuring API Gateway to send proxy requests to Lambda. This provides you with not only the request body but all of the headers.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html